# Copy files to several USB Sticks with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have to copy files to a lot of USB-Sticks. Therefore I´m trying to write me a short applescript. I´m not familiar with applescript so it would be great if someone can give me some hints.

What I have so far:

10 places USB-Hub

A short script to rename the sticks.

Now I´m stuck in copying the files to every stick which is connected:

```
property ignoredVolumes : {"Macintosh HD", "Time Machine Backups"}     

set myPath to ("Macintosh HD:Users:myusername:USB-Stick") as string
tell application "System Events"
set rootVolume to disk item (POSIX file "/Volumes" as text)
set allVolumes to name of every disk item of rootVolume
repeat with aVolume in allVolumes
    if aVolume is not in ignoredVolumes then
        set name of disk item (path of rootVolume & aVolume) to "Stickname"
    end if
end repeat
end tell
```

What I now need to do is to copy from myPath to every USB-Stick which is connected. Because they all get the same name, they will mounted with numbers behind the name (Stickname, Stickname 1,Stickname 2, ...)

So I need to add in my loop the copy command to the just renamed stick.

Hope someone could give me a helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to do with a shell script:

```
do shell script "cp -R ~/USB-Stick/ /Volumes/Stickname*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
property ignoredVolumes : {"Macintosh HD", "Time Machine Backups", "iDisk", "net", "home"}
set myPath to (path to home folder as text) & "USB-Stick:"
tell application "System Events" to set theDisks to every disk
repeat with aDisk in theDisks
    if aDisk's name is not in ignoredVolumes then
        set diskPath to path of aDisk
        tell application "Finder" to duplicate myPath to diskPath with replacing
    end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your hints. I solved it now with the following code:

```
property ignoredVolumes : {"Macintosh HD", "Time Machine Backups"}   -- add as needed
property counter : 0
tell application "System Events"
set rootVolume to disk item (POSIX file "/Volumes" as text)
set allVolumes to name of every disk item of rootVolume
set StartTime to (get current date)
repeat with aVolume in allVolumes
    if aVolume is not in ignoredVolumes then
        set newName to "XXX" & counter as string
        log newName & " in Progress... "
        set name of disk item (path of rootVolume & aVolume) to newName
        set counter to counter + 1
        set scr to ("cp ~/USB-Stick/* /Volumes/" & newName)
        do shell script scr
        set name of disk item (path of rootVolume & newName) to "XXX"
        do shell script "diskutil unmount /Volumes/XXX"
        log newName & " finished."
    end if
end repeat
set endTime to (get current date)
set dur to (endTime - StartTime)
display dialog "Process took " & dur & "seconds."
end tell
```

Hope this will helps other with the same problem.

Only one cosmetic problem: The call of the two shell scripts throws an error -10004 but still works. Tried with tell Application "Finder" or "Terminal" but error remains and has been added by other errors so i stick with my origin solution.

Kind Regards